# conda not putting python on path anymore?

Tags: python, ubuntu, path, conda, miniconda

I'm on Ubuntu 19.10; I remember always being able to run `python` and getting an Anaconda `python3` prompt in the past. However, I just installed the most recent version of `miniconda3` and confirmed as well when it asked whether it could modify my `.bashrc`. Now when I close and reopen my terminal and type `python`, I just get

```
Command 'python' not found, but can be installed with:
...
```

In my `.bashrc`, I can also see that the relevant directory is only added to `PATH` under a certain condition:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/tobi/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/tobi/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/tobi/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
```

Why is this - is it intended now that you can't just type `python` anymore to use your conda python or did I mess something up?

Comment: you can add `conda activate base` to your `.bashrc` to have python in the path.

Comment: Oh so it's mandatory to be on an environment?

Comment: Actually, it always used to be like this - the base environment was activated implicitly before - now you have to do it explicitly.

Comment: Thank you! I'll gladly accept your comments as answer if you wanna write one

Comment: You can use ``conda config --set auto_activate_base false`` or ``conda config --set auto_activate_base true``. This sets your desired settings in ``.condarc``.